# How to play audio files with discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to get my bot to play an audio file when it joins the vc. It is able to join but when it tries to play the audio file there are errors. I've tried de-bugging quite a bit but I'm really not sure whats wrong.

```
(node:13128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:107:11)
    at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:407:3)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:543:16)
```

```
msg.member.voiceChannel.join().then(connection =>{

                            const dispatcher = connection.playFile('C:/audio/audio.mp3');
                            dispatcher.on("end", end => {msg.member.voiceChannel.leave()});
                        })
```

Comment: Are you sure that these are the lines, that produce the error? Doesn't necessary look wrong to me. You might want to provide more code.

Comment: at c:\index.js:528:59
the line "const dispatcher = connection.playFile('C:/audio/audio.mp3');" is at 528 so I know it is that line, plus if I comment them it runs fine